# Silence/Pauses in audio file leads to Google Speech to Text transcription ending early

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-speech

I am using Google Speech to Text API to convert FLAC audio files using the synchronous Recognize intent in Python3. However, when the audio file contains short pauses or silences, the transcription ends early and response does not capture the text after the pause/silence.

```py
        audiofile = self.convert_mp3_to_flac(audiofile)
        with io.open(audiofile, 'rb') as audio_file:
            content = audio_file.read()
        audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
        config = types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
            sample_rate_hertz=24000,
            language_code='en-US',
            enable_automatic_punctuation=True)
        response = self.client.recognize(config, audio)
```

The response object does not contain transcription for speech after silences in the audio file.

I expect to see the entire transcription since I am making the request with the entire audio file.

Comment: Were you able to solve this @kevin-kim?

Answer (score 0):

Is the source of the audio produced with a noise canceling mic?  One work around is to add some white noise to the audio.